# How do I go about removing the lowest int in a Stack<Integer>?

Tags: java, stack

I am trying to make a method that both returns and removes the lowest int of a Stack. If the lowest number occurs multiple times, then they all must be dropped. I know how to return the lowest int but I am not sure how to remove it from a stack since in a stack, I can only remove the top. Can anyone give me an idea on how to solve this problem? I honestly have no clue. Any help I would appreciate! Thanks!

Comment: You can create another stack, pop elements from original stack and push them into the new one except the minimum integer. And then move the elements back to the original stack.

Comment: Post the code you have and we will help you from there.

Comment: Is this a `java.util.Stack`, or something else?

Comment: Why a stack? Priority queue seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in a single stack, I think this not possible.
Because of the stack structure must add the elements at the tail, and fetch the elements at the tail, first-in-last-out.
So you can use Kartik's idea, write a combination of structures that you need, Or change your collections.

Comment: It _would_ be possible with just the original stack if you can perform a "roll" or "rotate", where an item is popped off from the tail and replaced back at the head end.  The logic is a lot simpler, though, if you just use a second temporary stack.